# Dropbox file upload API to attach file with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to upload file to drop box using dropbox API. 
I am referring to this [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload,), based on that I have following code in my Angular application.

Here suppose, I want to upload file myImage.jpg from my local c: directory to dropbox users root folder.

```
 var headData = {"path": "/myImage.jpg", "mode": "add", "autorename": true, "mute": false };
    //So above path parameter pointing to Path in the my Dropbox root to save the file

    var config = {
        headers:  {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer <I have my access Token here>',
            'Dropbox-API-Arg': headData,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
        }
    };

    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.dropBoxAPI = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload";

    $http.post($scope.dropBoxAPI, $scope.data,config).success( function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

And, as API says it accept binary file which needs to be sent attached during post request.

```
--data-binary @C:\myImage.jpg
```

In above code **$scope.data** is completely empty as I don't know how do I use this to attach file. Please guide me, Is there something am doing wrong or missing anything?

Comment: Side note: you probably want `'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify(headData)`.

Comment: What kind of thing are you trying to upload? (What do you have now?) A `File` object? A `Blob`? An `ArrayBuffer`? Something else?

Comment: Try adding `transformations: []` to your `config` and then just passing whatever you have as the second parameter to `$http.post`. If that doesn't work, answer the above question about what kind of object you have. :-)

Comment: Hi smarx ,Thanks for reply. I am using file object to upload (now its image file around 2 Mb in size but it can be anything like pdf,text,doc) and was tried to pass this object as second parameter to $http post. I will try transformation:[ ] as you suggested

Comment: Note: `transformations`, not `transformation`

Comment: Hi smarx, do I have to pass anything into transformations:[] , as I have used it directly and placed it inside config->headers {} also passed file object as second parameter to $http.post. But still it throws 400 Bad Request. am I using transformations : [ ] correctly?

Comment: It doesn't go in `headers`, it goes directly in `config`. Maybe share your latest code.

Comment: Hi smarx, Thank you so much it worked after I cleared cache. Adding transformations : [ ] into config and editing confing->headers as 'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify(headData) worked well. Thank you again.